# Functional difference? pkill vs. rosnode kill

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm just curious if there's a preferred way to kill a node or if it's all the same underneath.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/274448/functional-difference?-pkill-vs.-rosnode-kill/) by [AndyZe](https://answers.ros.org/users/21281/andyze/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2331 on 2017-10-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`pkill` is an OS utility that uses OS infrastructure to forcibly terminate the process that is your node. The node gets notified that this is going to happen via various [signals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal_(IPC)), which it can use to perform pre-shutdown operations. See also [pkill(1)](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pkill).

`rosnode kill` will use the XML-RPC server in each node to send it (something akin to) a service request (`shutdown(..)`, see [ROS/Slave_API](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Slave_API)) that will set some client-lib internal variable(s) that eventually cause it exit any `while(ros::ok()) { .. }` or `ros::spin()` loops. The node may then perform any cleanup actions it has defined.

> I'm just curious if there's a preferred way to kill a node or if it's all the same underneath.

No, it's not the same, and I would say it is *probably* nicer to use `rosnode kill`, as the signals that `pkill` uses may not make it to the process hosting your node, but even if they do, they may not give your node (and the middleware infrastructure running in the same process) enough time to gracefully shut down.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-10-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-10-29**:
Note also that there is no authentication or other form of security on `shutdown(..)`, so it provides a nice way to take down an entire ROS application as a 'bad actor'.